# Call function inside Joomla articles

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am facing a problem. I have created a article in Joomla administrator and i have created a function in a php file. I have to call that function in that article . I don't know how do i call function in article. 
Here is the code:

```
class modVodesbalanceHelper {
function deductBalance()
    {
         $db        = JFactory::getDBO();
        $result = null;

        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        if ($user->guest) {
            return false;
        }

        $query = 'SELECT credit' .
                 ' FROM #__vodes_credits' .
                 ' WHERE userid = ' . (int) $user->id
                 ;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();

        $result_final=$result-10;


$query = 'update #__vodes_credits SET credit='.$result_final.
                 ' WHERE userid = ' . (int) $user->id
                 ;
//echo $query;
 $db->setQuery($query);


        $result = $db->loadResult();

    }
    }

In admin panel, in article i have write this code:
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
var a=confirm("do you want to purchase this credit");
if(a)
{
 document.location.href ="index.php?option=com_content&view=featured";
}
else
{
 document.location.href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3";
}
}
</script>
I have to call  deductBalance when user click on the "OK" of comfirm box.
Please tell me to sought it .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) to add php code inside joomla article.

Check the sourcerer plugin to be enabled (check plugin enabled status here: extensions->plugin manager->sourcerer).

Then, use the `"Insert Code"` button at the bottom of your WYSIWYG editor when adding your PHP scripts. Your code should be wrapped with

```
{source} 
//php code wrapped by <?php ?>
{/source}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add PHP to Joomla article by default. For this you need to use a 3rd party plugin. Personally, I would recommend using [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer). Once installed and enabled, you can use the following in your article:

```
{source}
<?php
  // All your PHP code
?>
{/source}
```

Don't include PHP files inside your article

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use code directly within Joomla article then use Sourcerer as in above questions. If you feel to keep the PHP code in seperate module. Use [Blank Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/3668)
Or [mod_php](https://code.google.com/p/joomla-php/downloads/detail?name=mod_php-J1.6-Alpha1.zip&can=2&q=) module. Then in your Joomla Article you can place the code like this,

```
{loadposition}*Your Custom Module Position*{/loadposition}
```